# How could parent directive's controller call a method from child directive's controller and vice versa?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 directives, <parent-directive> and <child-directive>. <parent-directive> has its controller called "parentCtrl" and <child-directive> has its controller called "childCtrl"

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

    myApp.directive("parentDirective", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "parent.html",
        controller: [
          "$scope",
          function($scope) {
            var self = this;
        
            var parentSayHello = function(){
              console.log("Hello from parent");
            };


            var callChildSayHello = function(){
              // want to call the say hello method defined in childCtrl here
              // ...
            };

          }
        ],
        controllerAs: "parentCtrl"
      };
    });

myApp.directive("childDirective", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "child.html",
        controller: [
          "$scope",
          function($scope) {
            var self = this;
        
            var childSayHello = function(){
              console.log("Hello from child");
            };

            var callParentSayHello = function(){
              // want to call the say hello method defined in parentCtrl here
              // ...
            };


          }
        ],
        controllerAs: "childCtrl"
      };
    });
```

In html, parentDirective and childDirective are nested directives:

```
    <parent-directive>
          <child-directive></child-directive>
    </parent-directive>
```

How could parent directive's controller call a method from child directive's controller and vice versa? (i.e., how to implement callChildSayHello & callParentSayHello as shown in the JS code above)

Comment: You can use service to do it. BTW, why you use directive instead of component? It should be easier for you to migrate to new NG later.

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate), Best Practice is to use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives.

Detail examples could be found in the link.

You can also call parent (directive/component) method in child directive via '&' function input:

JS:

```
angular.module('yourModule').directive('childDirective', [function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            callback: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'xxx.html'
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<child-directive callback="methdoInParentDirective()"></child-directive>
```